# How does one execute a no-op in C/C++?

Tags: c++

for the following:

```
( a != b ) ? cout<<"not equal" : cout<<"equal";
```

suppose I don't care if it's equal, how can I use the above statement by substituting `cout<<"equal"` with a no-op.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement no-op macro (or template) in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306611/how-do-i-implement-no-op-macro-or-template-in-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it really is for a ternary operator that doesn't need a second action, the best option would be to replace it for an if:

```
if (a!=b) cout << "not equal";
```

it will smell a lot less.

Comment: That doesn't work if it is used as an expression. "if" is not an expression in C.

Comment: So? The idea is exactly avoid doing that kind of ugly expression in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Simple: I would code it as

```
if (a != b)
   cout << "not equal";
```

The ternary operator requires the two results to be of the same type.  So you might also be able to get away with

```
(a != b) ? cout << "not equal" : cout;
```

because the stream operator (<<) just returns the ostream reference.  That's ugly and unnecessary in my opinion though.

Answer (score 8):

`(void)0;` is noop. There is a lots of good reason to use `expr?false:true` form. Look how assert() is implemented.

So in your example, use `( a != b ) ? (void)0 : cout<<"equal";`

Answer (score 5):

The only thing missing from the other answers is this:
There is no way, directly, to code a "noop" in C/C++.

Also, doing: `(a != b) ? : printf("equal\n");` does actually compile for me (gcc -ansi in gcc 4.2.4).

Comment: This isn't entirely true. An empty block may act as “no-op”. However, this isn't an *expression*. Since an expression must be typed in C++, there's no literal/constant that is universally acceptable as “no-value”. “no-op” isn't really the right word here.

Comment: gcc has an extension that allows leaving out the middle term, but it's not legal C or C++.

Comment: @bames53 What is the extension name?

Comment: @user997112 GCC docs refer to "Conditionals with Omitted Operands"

Answer (score 4):

The following will achieve what you're looking for, however, it may not be clear to people reading your code *why* it works:

```
(a != b) && (cout << "equal");
```

Personally, I agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300208/how-does-one-execute-a-no-op-in-cc#300225) answer from Vinko Vrsalovic.

Comment: That's interesting hack, but for readability reasons I'd recommend not to use it. Also, you shouldn't rely on compiler optimalization.

Comment: @ya23, could you be more precise about what optimization he relies upon? That expression is well-defined in all optimization contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing code. You *could* just write

```
cond ? cout << "equal" : cout;
```

but you won't (will you?) because you've got conventional `if` for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the operator : has two EXPRESSIONS as arguments.
Let's say..
a = x ? y : z;

Expression by definition must have a value...that's why you cannot just "skip".

Answer (score 1):

If the focus of the code is the output operation and not the condition, then something like this could be done:

```
cout << (cond ? "not equal" : "");
```

I suspect that's not the case, though, because you want to do nothing in the "else" clause.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can write ( in case of void ) :

```
somecondition ? foo() : [] {} () ;
```

So the NOP is actually an empty lambda.
Besides void you could return any type and value.

This might look a bit overkill all by itself but suppose you have this :

```
somecondition1 ? foo1() :
somecondition2 ? foo2() :
somecondition3 ? foo3() :
                 flip_out_because_unhandled_condition() ;
```

Now if someone adds somecondition4, but forgets to include it in the handling code, the software will call the flip_out_... function causing all kinds of unwanted effects.
But maybe somecondition4 doesn't need any special attention, it just needs to be ignored.
Well then you could write :

```
somecondition1 ? foo1()   :
somecondition2 ? foo2()   :
somecondition3 ? foo3()   :
somecondition4 ? []{}() :
                 flip_out_because_unhandled_condition() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a!=b) cout<<"not equal";
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax just requires a expression. You can just go:
(a!=b)?cout<<"not equal":1;

Comment: what is the resultant type of that expression? Int or Stream?

Comment: won't work: standard: (C ? E1 : E2) in the following: if E1 or E2 has a nonclass type, E1 can be converted to match E2 if E1 can be implicitly converted to the type that expression E2 would have if E2 were converted to an
rvalue (or the type it has, if E2 is an rvalue).)

Answer (score 0):

Both statements compile:

```
( a != b ) ? cout<<"not equal" : NULL;

( a != b ) ? NULL : cout<<"equal";
```