# Debugging in C/C++: cost of calling an empty function

Tags: c++, c, debugging

One normal procedure to implement debugging is the use of

```
#ifdef DEBUG

...debugging tests...

#endif
```

Sometimes, a typical "checking" algorithm is needed in some parts of the code, and so one would normally like to wrap it on a function, such that the code is only called when DEBUG flag is defined. Let that function be called myDebug();

I see two natural approaches for this: either ifdef is added on each time myDebug() is called, like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

myDebug();

#endif
```

Or myDebug is defined as:

```
void myDebug()
{
#ifdef DEBUG

...code...

#endif
}
```

Basically, the first avoids the function calling, while the second avoid putting the code with a lot of #ifdef/#endif.

Is there any "standard" convention to choose one of the two, or another way that I don't know? Is is worth to choose the second from the "styling" point of view?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. The title talks about the *cost*, but the rest of your question doesn't really focus on that, but just asks which approach is preferable. What are you asking, exactly? Does the precise performance cost of each option matter?

Comment: Though most compilers will optimize an empty function, I would  personally choose the first option..

Comment: Using optimisation, an empty function will probably be ignored

Comment: The empty function *can* be optimized if the compiler has access to it - i.e. it knows its empty. It can or can not happen.

Comment: See [`#ifdef` Considered Harmful](http://www.ethernut.de/pdf/ifdefs.pdf)

Comment: [NO-OP in c/c++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306611/how-do-i-implement-no-op-macro-or-template-in-c

Comment: See also [C #define macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing) and [DEBUG macros in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251038/debug-macros-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd go with number 3:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define myDebug(x) myDebug(x)
#else
#define myDebug(x) {}
#endif
```

This way, there's no pesky `#ifdef`s everywhere in the code, and for a non-debug build no code will be generated.

Comment: +1 I would change `#define myDebug(x)` to `#define myDebug(x) {}` to avoid warnings

Comment: Or better to `#define myDebug(x) {(void)x;}` to dismiss warning `unused variable 'x'`

Comment: @Binyamin: `do { } while (false)` should be used rather than `{ }` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac

Comment: @TonyDelroy - You're right, I actually remembered something like that, but not exactly..