# Question about using #define value in if condition and code generation: debug vs release build

Tags: c, linux

Question is related to release and debug build. Something related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/define-macro-for-debug-printing-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684961/better-way-to-nullify-debug-functions-in-c)

But I have a simple doubt for example if I do following: (file is debug-test.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define debug  1

int sum (int a, int b){

  if (debug){
    if (a > 0 && b > 0){
      fprintf (stderr, "a(%d) >0 && b(%d)\n", a,b);
    }
  }
  return (a+b);
}

int main (void){

  int a = 10, b = 5;
  printf ("a:%d + b:%d = %d\n", a, b, sum(a,b));
  
  return 0;
}
```

So my doubt/question is if I do `#define debug  0` will compiler eliminate/optimize out all the code (that `if condition`) from final binary? Or code will remain in final binary as

```
if (0){
   .....
}
```

I have lots of testing and other code that just checks execution in various logical conditions.

What I tried is using  `gcc -S -Wall -Wextra debug-test.c` once with debug set to 0 and once debug set to 1.

With debug set to 1 I get something like following:

```
        .file   "debug-test.c"
        .text
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "a(%d) >0 && b(%d)\n"
        .text
        .globl  sum
        .type   sum, @function
sum:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
```

When I set debug to 0 I get following

```
       .file   "debug-test.c"
        .text
        .globl  sum
        .type   sum, @function
sum:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
```

I do not really understand output of `-S` but cursory glance shows that
`.string "a(%d) >0 && b(%d)\n"`   is not present when I set debug to 0.  Other simple thing that I checked is `wc -l debug-test.s`  so for 0 it gives me 61 lines and for 1 it gives me 78 lines. I am not sure I really understand what is happening, will compiler eliminate code or keep it in binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I do #define debug  0 will compiler eliminate/optimize out all the code (that if condition) from final binary?

Yes, if optimizations are enabled. I just tried your code on x86 gcc `-O3` and it removed the whole function call with `debug` set to zero. Basically it just loads the numbers `5`, `10` and `15` as parameters to printf then calls it, and that's all the program does. https://godbolt.org/z/b3f17rqe4

An issue here is that the compiler might give you spurious warnings "condition is always false" and similar for `if(0)`. Which is why `#ifdef debug ... #endif` is a better pattern to use.

Comment: FYI gcc `-O1` should be sufficient to enable dead code elimination (`-fdce`), at least according to the GCC docs. Although it looked like OP's example was doing some dead code elimination even without setting the optimisation level (equivalent to `-O0`).

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah so it seems, though the function inlining doesn't happen at `-O0`.

Answer (score 4):

Any reasonable behaving compiler will optimize everything away when you define debug to zero. However, there is no guarantee so a better solution is:

```
#ifdef debug
    if (a > 0 && b > 0){
      fprintf (stderr, "a(%d) >0 && b(%d)\n", a,b);
    }
#endif
```

Comment: OP defines `debug` as `0` or `1`, so that should be `#if debug`.

Comment: In some codebases I've worked on, we deliberately chose to rely on the compiler optimizing out `if (0) { ... }`, rather than use preprocessor conditions, because that way the code inside the condition would always be _parsed_ and checked for syntax errors, and it was less likely to bit-rot.

Comment: @zwol That's an interesting argument. Doesn't that mean you have to disable warnings for "condition is always false" locally inside every file though? Because that one isn't something I'd want to disable project-wide.

Comment: But a #define in main header file will visible in all files no?

Comment: @zwol Well, I understand your idea but on the other hand, I would expect the test system to compile and test the relevant combination. Catching syntax errors is one thing but the functional part is equally important.

Comment: @AvalSarri : thé #define will only be visible in main.c . To have it visible in all files, either you add it in a .h file included in all c files.

Comment: @Lundin This was long enough ago that I don't remember whether the compiler, at the time, even _had_ "condition is always false" warnings.

Comment: @4386427 This was many years ago -- before ubiquitous CI -- and even with CI, it's better if the test build on the developer's local machine catches the mistake.

Comment: @zwol Apparently current gcc doesn't warn for it even with maximum warnings, which I find strange. Maybe it only checks more complex expressions. I'd expect a compiler warning for this: `for(unsigned char i=255; i>0; i--);` but nope...

Comment: @Lundin: `i>0` is not always true.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant `i>=0`... but that explains why I didn't get a warning :) Monday and not nearly enough coffee...